# Getting first row of a type in ngFor of Angular 2

Tags: angular, ngfor

So, I have data like (Angular 2)

```
[
{text: "first", name: "a"},
{text: "rw", name: "a"},
{text: "ds", name: "b"},
{text: "asdf", name: "b"},
{text: "ASDF", name: "b"},
{text: "ertre", name: "b"}
{text: "hf", name: "c"}
]
```

I have to use that data to show the list of the content but in the way like

```
<div>a</div>
<p>a's text 1</p>
<p>a's text 2</p>
<p>a's text 3</p>
<div>b</div>
<p>b's text 1</p>
<p>b's text 2</p>
<p>b's text 3</p>
```

Is this possible without creating custom filters? Means simply, if else in ng repeat `*ngFor`.

Basically I would do `ngIf` to show header `div` if its first occurance for that value (we can check if `a==a` then hide header, `b==a` then show header).

Comment: Some information on creating pipes, including custom pipes: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#

Comment: You will need to preprocess your data. You cannot do this kind of logic in templates.

Comment: @R.Richards that is actually feasible but was asking without using pipes. torazaburo that is something doable, just wanted to avoid that step

Comment: @Luckyy Sorry, when I saw custom filter, I assumed pipe. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<ng-container>`. See how to [Group sibling elements with `<ng-container>`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#ng-container).

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="a!=='a'">
 <div>a</div>
 <p>a's text 1</p>
 <p>a's text 2</p>
 <p>a's text 3</p>
</ng-container>
```